# Windows Phone 7 buttons

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Is it just me or the property Visibility.Hidden on buttons are not included in Windows Phone 7?

Because as far as I know there are three types of Visibility properties for a control, either Visible, Collapsed or Hidden.

I need the hidden value, why it only shows Visible or Collapsed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like you said, Visible and Collapsed are the only options you have for the Visibility of the control.

The hidden functionality you want can be achieved by setting the visibilty to Visible and the Opacity to 0. Take care, your button will be hidden, but still clickable, and the layout of the UI will not be affected.

If you want to hide the button and adjust the UI accordingly, set the visibility to Collapsed. This will re-order the UI.

Comment: Haha, yes. Silly of me not thinking of the Opacity property just to simply hide it. And set the opacity back to 1 to make it visible. Thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 4):

Visibility.Hidden is not included in Silverlight. It is only available in WPF as of now. And since WP7 is Silverlight, you don't get it in there, too.

[Related question on Silverlight.](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/26569.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

See , There are only two properties available  `Button.visibility=visibility.collapsed` or `Visibility.Visible`. If you want to hide it turn the opacity feature to minimum value or you can always disable the button